# Can't mute microphone on a motorola

Tags: android, microphone, android-audiomanager

I am working on an android project. I would like to set the micrphone on mute when licking a button. Using this code:

```
AudioManager audioManager = ((AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE));
audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(true);
```

everything works ok, **EXCEPT motorola**.

On morotola, the microphone is not set to mute. Can someone please give me an advice?

#### EDIT

I found this:

```
Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MUTE));
getBaseContext().sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp,"android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
```

How to now use this code in order to unmute the call?

Comment: Please check this answer .

http://stackoverflow.com/a/6562119/614807

Comment: thank you for your reply. How to unmute a Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
      buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MUTE));
      getBaseContext().sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp,"android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");