# Can't set microphone mute - Android

Tags: android, microphone, android-audiomanager

I'm trying to mute my microphone in my Android application

```
audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(true);
```

I also added the permission in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

However, when I speak to my application, the logs return me exactly what I said which means the microphone is not muted.

Even the logs tell me that the mic should be muted. This :

```
Log.d("Muted ? : ", String.valueOf(audioManager.isMicrophoneMute()));
```

Display this log :

```
Muted ? : true
```

I really don't know what could be the problem.
Do you have any idea about that ?

Comment: It's not clear to me: `audioManager.isMicrophoneMute() == true` but it is really not mute?

Comment: Exactly. Even though it says it is mute, i can speak to my application and it receive what I say.

Comment: Do you solve your problem? I have same problem that need your help

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same, i thought the problem was in all devices, but some devices can mute their microphone, i tried the same solution of this answer:

[setMicrophoneMute(boolean) doesn't work on some devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217437/setmicrophonemuteboolean-doesnt-work-on-some-devices)

> i simulate a press on mute button on the handsfree kit . it worked for
>   me hope it will help you too here is the code:

```
Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
getBaseContext().sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp,"android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to copy this code into my onCreate() method but my application can still uses the microphone...

Answer (score 0):

The Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 and Motorola Xoom work as you would expect. Call audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(true) to mute and audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(false) to unmute